# CodeIgniter Creating Core Base Classes not working like User Guide

Tags: codeigniter

I want to extend `CI_Controller` as a base class for my other classes according do my own need.

I read the [user guid](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html). Acted as what it told me.

I created application core:

./application/core/MY_ControllerPermission.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class MY_ControllerPermission extends CI_Controller 
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

And this is my controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

if(class_exists('MY_ControllerPermission'))
    echo 'clase does exist';
else
    echo 'clase does not exist';

class Users extends MY_ControllerPermission
{
    ....
```

In my config file:

```
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';
```

It just show blank page and "clase does not exist"

So where is the problem?

---

**UPDATE**

If I add this line:

```
include_once(APPPATH . 'core/MY_ControllerPermission.php');
```

before my controller, it would work. Doesn't CodeIgniter load core PHP files automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename `MY_ControllerPermission.php` to `MY_Controller.php` and you should be good to go.

You can leave everything else the same, you don't even need to use the name `MY_Controller` for your class if you don't want to.

Comment: worked like charm. what's wrong with previous name? is **MY_Controller.php** a mandatory name and all classes should be defined in there?

Comment: Yep, that's the way it works. Same thing if you wanted to extend any other core class or non-core library (although core classes are prefixed with `CI_`). It's a little weird.